# Refresh com Parâmetro em Iframe utilizando jquery - API Google Maps V3 - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, google-maps

Estou com problemas ao utilizar a API do Google Maps V3 (usando o Codeigniter). A view que recebe o mapa não possui formatação nenhuma a não ser aquela já fornecida pela API. 
Desta forma, criei um iframe que carrega essa view dentro da página onde pretendo usá-la e um form recebendo o local onde o usuário está, para que assim seja feito o mapa até o local do estabelecimento que está fixo. 
O problema é que preciso passo por é que não sei como atualizar o iframe e com ele criar o mapa de destino.
Seguem abaixo os códigos:

Controller:

```php
class Localizacao extends CI_Controller
{
    public $estilo = 'css/responsivo/estilo.css';
    public $header = 'css/header.css';
    public $principal = 'css/principal.css';
    function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();

    //Carregamento dos helpers na página
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'html', 'url'));
    $this->load->library(array('googlemaps','input'));
}

function index()
{
    //Carrgando dados a view
    $dados = array(
                'titulo' => 'Titulo',
                'estilo' => $this->estilo,
                'header' => $this->header,
                'principal' => $this->principal,
                'formulario' => array(
                                    'id' => 'traca-rota',
                                    'class' => 'form-rota',
                                    ),
                );
    $this->load->view('localizacao_view', $dados);
}

function mapa($local = NULL)
{
    if($local == NULL)
        $localizacao = 'Endereço de Destino';
    else
        $localizacao = preg_replace("-", " ", $local);

    $config['center'] = 'Endereço de destino';
    $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
    $config['directions'] = TRUE;
    $config['directionsStart'] = $localizacao;
    $config['directionsEnd'] = 'Endereço de Destino';
    $config['directionsDivID'] = 'directionsDiv';

    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

    $this->load->view('mapa_view', $data);
}
}
```

View locazizacao_view:

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php';  ?>
<?php echo form_open('#', $formulario); ?>
    <input type="text" name="localizacao">
    <input type="submit" value="Traçar Rota" id="traca_rota">
<?php form_close(); ?>
<div id="fora">
    <iframe src="<?php echo base_url('/localizacao/mapa/'); ?> " frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

View mapa_view:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $map['js']; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
    <div id="directionsDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Método que manda parâmetro para a view 'mapa_view':

```js
$('#traca-rota').submit(function(){
    var dados = $( this ).serialize();
    var action = "http://urldosite.com/localizacao/mapa";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: dados,
        success: function( data )
        {
                            //Evitar refresh em página
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false; //Faz com que o Formulário Não envie seus dados da Maneira Tradicional
});
```

Caso alguém souber alguma outra forma de fazer a integração contendo as informações de Saída/Destino ou se alguém souber a solução desse problema, ficarei muito agradecido.

Comment: desculpe, não entendi corretamente.

Você deseja melhorar este código é isso?

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja apenas atualizar o iframe talvez este link ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe

Teste colocar a tag target no seu formulário, com o id do iframe.

Comment: Veja isso: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links Para a resposta ser interessante para todos, para ser localizada por buscadores, ela precisa ter conteúdo, mesmo que tenha que trazer o conteúdo do link (se for permitido e ainda manter uma referência para ele)

Answer (score 0):

por acaso o que você pretende fazer seria algo assim [link](http://parkhoteltermasmachadinho.com.br/como-chegar/)?

Essa é uma página para o usuário traçar a roda até o hotel, fiz este site na agência em que trabalho há bem pouco tempo.

A API 3 do Google Maps é excelente, inclusive existe uma secção inteira falando sobre como traçar rodas com o Google Maps em português, segue o [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=pt-br)

Tá super bem explicado, inclusive tem um código de exemplo pronto que você poderá usar de referência, o que eu posso te explicar é que basicamente você terá variáveis globais em seu código, uma delas é o objeto do Mapa que você criará na página.
Outra função será criada para renderizar o mapa na página.
E outra função para você chamar todas as vezes que o usuário dará o submit no formulário enviando os dados da origem, passe essa origem como parâmetro dessa função.

**OBS:** não esqueça de deixar com o submit do formulário retornando falso, caso contrário a página sempre será recarregada a cada submit e o script não funcionará.